# Assign only one name to a matrix R

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to assign a name to a matrix, not to every component to the matrix like R does, example:

```
a <- matrix(1:10, nrow=5)
names(a)

NULL

names(a) <- "this is a"
a

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
attr(,"names")
 [1] "this is a" NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

I would like that `names(a)` result on "This is a" only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attribute.  For a `vector`, the `names` are the names for each element.  So, assigning with `names` for a single element result in filling other elements with `NA`.  An option is to directly create an attribute

```
attr(a, "name") <- "this is a"
a
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    6
#[2,]    2    7
#[3,]    3    8
#[4,]    4    9
#[5,]    5   10
#attr(,"name")
#[1] "this is a"
```

NOTE: It may be better to use a different value rather than `names`

---

The attributes can be accessed via

```
attributes(a)$name
#[1] "this is a"

attr(a, "name")
#[1] "this is a"
```